# В bootstrap как увеличить ширину container вправо (как на картинке)?

Tags: bootstrap

[image: Нужно получить такой результат]Как увеличить ширину для container вправо (как на картинке)?
Как убрать правое поле для контейнера в bootstrap?

Comment: наверное переписать класс ".container", а именно "margin: 0 0 0 auto;" ему поставить.

Comment: Таким способом не получается, левое поле увеличивается. а должно остаться как было

Comment: Вам именно контейнер нужно так растянуть или только задний фон?

Comment: Если контейнер, тогда следует писать ширину контейнера в процентах, так как разрешение мониторов у всех разные и вы не сможете правильно выстроить ширину задавая точные цифры.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой есть вариант, надеюсь сможете применить к своей вёрстке.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 400px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Так не получается. Задача - увеличить ширину container на ширину правого марджина, левое поле остается прежним. С адаптивностью. Высоту задать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, Вы хотели увидеть что-то подобное. P.S. нажмите "выполнить код" и разверните результат на всю страницу

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Container</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-danger">Container-fluid
      <div class="row ms-5 bg-success">
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```